# Passing array between forms and managing in arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, parameter-passing

I want to transfer an array from Form1 to Form2, then on Form2 add some values to the array.
On Form1 button click I put this code:

```
        int[] arrayOfInt = new int[4];
        arrayOfInt[0] = 19;
        arrayOfInt[1] = 12;
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.TakeThis(arrayOfInt);
        frm2.Show();
```

In the  form2 i created `TakeThis(int[])` that catches the values from the form1 and display the values of the array on a label. Now, i cannot figure how to add some values to array. For example `arrayOfInt[2]` and `arrayOfInt[3]` and send to Form3.

**Edit**:

I decided to use a List to store my data but at the end I must convert a 
list to an array because I am doing some reporting and math operations with the data.

*This example is different from the example above. In this store all inputs from textboxs,comboxes in the list. At the end i need to convert the list into an array.*

What have I done, 
I created a new global class:

```
static class List{

   static List<string> list;

   public static void NewList(){
   list=new List<string>();
   }

   public  static void Save(string value){
   list.Add(value);
   }

   public static void Display(){
   foreach(var value in list){
   MessageBox.Show(value);
   }
   }

}
```

The data is inserted between forms,

```
List.save(some_strings);
 ...
```

but at the end I need to convert the list in an array. I googled and I find the `ToArray()` function but i dont know how to use in my code. I tried with properties but i couldn't do the conversion. Please help.

**Edit2**
I found the solution.
In the global static class List I created a method that returns a List of strings:

```
public static List<string> GetList(){
              return list;
               }
```

Then, I created a new empty List of strings on Form2. Copied the old list to the new list and converted it in an array.

```
List<string> li=new List<string>();
li=List.GetList();
string[] temp=li.ToArray();
```

Comment: Better to ask a new question for your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use arrays if you want a data structure that you need to add items to.

Use a generic collection like [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

In your case, a list of integers would be a `List<int>`.

```
IList<int> listOfInt = new List<int>();
listOfInt.Add(19);
listOfInt.Add(12);
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.TakeThis(listOfInt);
frm2.Show();
```

When on `Form2`, your `TakeThis` function would look like this:

```
public voidTakeThis(IList<int> listOfInt)
{
  listOfInt.Add(34);
}
```

This will also work when passing the list to another form, as `List` is a reference type whereas arrays are value types. If you don't know what this means, see [this article](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Rather use `ArrayList` or even better `IList<T>`.
Arrays cannot be resized in C#

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `ref` argument on `frm2.TakeThis()` method:

Here is an MSDN article on it : [Passing Arrays Using ref and out (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730.aspx).

```
void TakeThis(ref Int32[] array)
{
    // Change array
}
```

and use like:

```
frm2.TakeThis(ref arrayOfInt);
```

Arrays need to passed by reference if you want to persist changes to them.

If you must not use an `Array` use a `Collection` like `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `List<Int>` and use `oList.Add(item)` method to add elements as array is Fixed in Lenght (you already giving  it size at a time of initialization)
But if you want to use array at any cost then make a logic to create a new array upto the size of Old+ new added element and return that.

**UPDATED**
I believe  you are facing problem because you have taken List of String instead or Int.

```
            List<int> oIntList = new List<int>();
            oIntList.Add(1);
            oIntList.Add(3);
            oIntList.Add(4);
            oIntList.Add(5);

            int[] oIntArr = oIntList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I decided to use List<> and in the end to convert to array. Now, i have some questions.See the edit.

Comment: why making `List` of `String` ??  Make it of type `Int`. And tell what problem you are facing right now? is it Conversion from List to Array or Sum of all elements??

Comment: Hi Fasih, I needed a global list. That i can insert strings between forms (eg. from textboxes,comboboxes). Then convert that global list into an array. Indexes of array help me to know where the data is(eg. txtbox1.text=>array[0],txtbox2=>array[2]).