# Store data to array to pass to second form

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am trying to do the form 1 and form 2:

**Form 1:** customers click on the radio button , the label will show the price.
I want to store the label price into the class array, so I can serializing the data in order to transfer to form 2 to show the order summary.

**Form 2:** display the order summary into the textbox

Please help!!!

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried, and why it is not working?

Comment: Quick but maybe not so pretty solution: Create your own form class, which inherits from `Form` ,then create a method which takes some data and then simply instantiate you custom form in `Form1` and call the method with the data you need to send.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in another question here [Passing array between forms and managing in arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469222/passing-array-between-forms-and-managing-in-arrays?rq=1)

Here is the answer:

Don't use arrays if you want a data structure that you need to add items to.

Use a generic collection like List.

In your case, a list of integers would be a List.

```
IList<int> listOfInt = new List<int>();
listOfInt.Add(19);
listOfInt.Add(12);
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.TakeThis(listOfInt);
frm2.Show();
```

When on Form2, your TakeThis function would look like this:

```
public voidTakeThis(IList<int> listOfInt)
{
  listOfInt.Add(34);
}
```

This will also work when passing the list to another form, as List is a reference type whereas arrays are value types.